# Replacing NaN values in a nested dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, nan

I want to replace the `NaN` values in a nested dictionary as below, `financial_features` is a list of certain keys of the main dictionary (`data_dict`)

but after I run the code below nothing changes

```
for name in data_dict:
    for feature in financial_features:
        if data_dict[name][feature] == 'NaN':
            data_dict[name][feature] == 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the last line:

```
data_dict[name][feature] == 0
```

The `==` operator only returns a Boolean value, it does not assign a value to either end of the expression. What you are looking for for the last line is the `=` operator:

```
for name in data_dict:
    for feature in financial_features:
        if data_dict[name][feature] == 'NaN':
            data_dict[name][feature] = 0
```